# Will reducing the mill gap cause haze?

Tags: crush

I recently adjusted the gap on my grain mill to give the smallest gap.  I was playing around with going as small as possible until I start to cause problems, i.e. stuck mash.

I've brewed very similar recipes only, changing one ingredient, about 5-6
times before. The only thing I can thing to blame the haze on is  the smaller crush.

Will a smaller crush cause a haze?

Batch - 10gallons

Grains: 
17 lb american 2 row
6.5 lb rye malt 
1.5 Munich malt
1.25 crystal 40

Hops:
60 min 2 oz magnum 14.7 aa
20 min 1 oz cascade 6.7aa
20 min 1 oz citra 12 aa
0 min 1 oz cascade 6.7 aa
0 min 1 oz citra 6.7aa

Yeast 
White labs WLP028 Edinburgh

Misc:
2 whirlfloc tablets for 20 min.

Mash at 150F

Boil for 60 min

Comment: Do you recirculate the mash? Did you notice the haze going into the boil kettle? What's the serving temperature and is it the same as previously?

Comment: Do you vorlauf?

Comment: One whirlfoc tab is good for 12 gal.  You can reduce your usage.

Comment: I mashed for 60 min and recirculated for 20 min, then collected.  I didn't notice anything unusual going into the kettle.  I keg the beer, which is all in the same fridge so it's all at the same temperature.

Answer (score 4):

No, I don't think a smaller crush will cause haze. The flour particles are fairly heavy and will clump together in the boil, and would definitely drop out during primary. (I use a fine crush and have not seen haze from that.)

For other causes of haze, see [What causes cloudiness in beer?](https://homebrew.stackexchange.com/questions/3957/what-causes-cloudiness-in-beer)